# When do I need to bind a socket?

Tags: c#, sockets

When do I need to bind a UDP socket?
This code throws an exception saying I need to bind the socket first

```
// server
Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
IPEndPoint remote = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0)
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
sock.ReceiveFrom(buffer, ref remote);
```

whereas this one doesn't

```
// client
Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
IPEndPoint server = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("server ip"), 1234);
byte[] toSend = { 1, 2, 3 };
sock.SendTo(toSend, server);
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
sock.ReceiveFrom(buffer, ref server);
```

I've had some theories, but none of them seems really plausible.

Comment: Generally you need to bind a socket before listening (receive call for UDP, listen call for TCP).  The socket may be bound to a random port automatically.  In the first case, no one could know the port chosen.  In the second case, the port could be discovered from the source information in the packet you sent out.

Comment: So basically in order to be able to call ReceiveFrom without binding explicitly, I have to send a packet first?

Comment: @user1046192 - It would be better practice to bind the socket explicitly before attempting to receive from the socket. You can duplicate the autobind done by the send by passing 0 as the bind port parameter.

Comment: I believe I have observed some operating systems will pick a different port for each sendto() call if a bind() call hasn't been made. Better to bind to port 0 so the OS will pick a random port (but then use it consistently for all subsequent sends) than to not call bind at all.

Comment: Okay, I'll stick to doing that from now on. :) Thanks. But why did you post these answers as comments instead of actual answers? I